# few faces into one

Tags: faces

It is possible make this few faces into one big face? Every face are the same z position
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why don't you simply draw a polygon face over the texture? Or (may be better) just one rectangle.

Comment: I agree with @lemon ,  go to your favorite image editing program. Arrange the images in a way that pleases you, save as a single image, and use that as a plane in blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it may be easier to do it directly in an image editor but what you can do is switch the *Film* to *Transparent* in the *Render* options:

[image]

Then choose the front orthographic view and in *View* > choose *Viewport Render Image* (or render an image with your camera in front and orthographic view). The generated image has an alpha transparent background:

[image]

Now crop your image in an image editor, load it in Blender and use it as an *Image Texture* for a large plane.

Comment: thank you, but its another way to connect all faces into one directly?

Comment: no idea comes to mind but i may miss something simple... you could also link-duplicate the image and parent them all to an empty but I guess it's not what you want